# why does it give error saying temp is undifined. The server runs and listens to port but as soon as i submit an input it gives the error

Tags: javascript, web-development-server, openweathermap

```js
const { query } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});


app.post("/",function(req,res){
    const query = req.body.cityName;
    const apiKey = "token";
    const units = "metric";
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ query +"&appid="+ apiKey +"&units="+ units;
    https.get(url, function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", function(data){
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            // console.log(weatherData);
            const temp1 = weatherData.list[0].main.temp;
            //const temp1 = weatherData.main.temo;
            const description = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            res.write("<h1>its " + description +" and "+temp1+"</h1>");
            res.send();
        });
        });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

why does it give an error saying temp is undefined. The server runs and listens to the port but as soon as I submit an input it gives the error.

[Please refer to this image for the error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tza9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you've posted it seems that API call returns `401 (Unauthorized)` which means that `main` key does not exist on return object. Since `main` is undefined you can't read `temp` from it.

**Also, I'm hoping that isn't your real API key. You shouldn't share it and should invalidate that one.**

Comment: It is my real key.  I am doing a course at udemy where almost all students face this problem and there is no valid answer in the Q&A section. But when the instructor runs the code in his/her machine it works fine.

Comment: Then you should invalidate/delete that key immediately, then generate a new one and not share it. Here's a guide on how to do it https://openweathermap.org/faq .

Comment: As for the bug itself, because you're getting 401, I think the key was either wrong or inactive at the time (on their FAQ page it says that it might take them up to 2 hours to activate it).

Comment: according to your advice, I have diactivated the key and generated a new one. The same error comes still. The 'temp' in 'weatherData.main.temp' is said undefined.